# Как сохранить данные в файл при закрытии формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Использую такой вот код для этого:

```
void Form1_FormClosed ( object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e )
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    sw.Close();
}
```

Все бы ничего, дак форма теперь закрываться не хочет. Чем лечить?

Самое удивительное то, что если файла не существует, то он создается (и это правильно, мне так и нужно) и форма при этом закрывается нормально. Но если же файл уже существует, то форма не закрывается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А может стоит изменить событие на Form_Closing? Ведь Вам надо сохранять данные в файл: "при закрытии формы? " А не когда форма уже закрыта...

Comment: нет, и при **Form_Closing** тоже самое.

Comment: Хм странно у меня всё нормально сохраняет

            private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("test.txt"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }

И всё нормально закрывается.

Comment: А, нашел причину, это я тут для примера test.txt написал, а на самом деле сохранял в файл settings.ini, видимо приложение как-то блокирует именно этот файл, т.е. он уже занят.

Comment: даже так получилась что у меня при старте приложения это файл открывается, а потом я его просто закрыть забыл StreamReadeMyFile.Close() нужно было добавить.

Comment: Я рад что у Вас всё работает :)