# Windows Forms: как передать параметры между двумя окнами

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть проблемка. У меня есть Главная форма, где происходит весь процесс програмы. Но я хочу добавить кнопочку "настройки", при нажатии на которую должна открываться другая форма, там будут текстбоксы, чекбоксы и т.п. Проблема в том, чтобы эти изменения сохранялись или передавались в главную форму и служили параметрами для используемых функций. Кто подскажет, как это реализовать попроще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если очень просто...

1) Сделайте классик, который будет содержать настройки:

```
public class Settings
{
    public string StringSetting { get; set; }

    public int IntSetting { get; set; }

    public bool BoolSetting { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

2) Дальше в форму настроек добавьте свойство с этими настройками, а также два места, где настройки будут считываться и "сохраняться":

```
public class SettingsForm
{
    ...

    public Settings Settings { get; set; }

    ...

    public void OnFormLoad(...) // условное название
    {
        textBox.Text = settings.StringSetting;
        checkBox.Checked = settings.BoolSetting;
    }

    public void OnFormClosing(...) // условное название
    {
        Settings.StringSetting = textBox.Text,
        Settings.BoolSetting = checkBox.Checked
    }
}
```

Подсказка: запоминание настроек можно заменить [дата байндингом](http://rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/Data_Binding_Basics.xml).

3) При вызове формы с настройками устанавливайте ей объект с актуальными настройками:

```
Settings settings = LoadSettings();
using (var frmSettings = new SettingsForm())
{
    frmSettings.Settings = settings;
    frmSettings.ShowDialog();
    SaveSettings(frmSettings.Settings);
}
```

`LoadSettings()` должен, соответственно, откуда-то считывать настройки, а `SaveSettings()` -- сохранять.

4) При запуске и [выходе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/132309/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B) из главной формы настройки должны считываться и сохраняться.

Comment: Да)) Все довольно просто, но работает так как было нужно. Спасибо большое!